# Laravel hasOne relationship where condition same table field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 5 tables `retailers, doctors, softwareproviders, members and contactpersons`. `contactpersons` table associated with other 4 tables using `type and refid`.

retailers

| id | name | contactno | mem_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | karthik | 855550 | 1 |

members

| id | name | contactno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | naveen | 855550 |

contactpersons

| id | type | refid | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | ruban |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | aron |

***type 1 - retailers, 2 - members, 3 - doctors, 4 - softwareproviders***

In contactpersons model how to make `hasone relationship` with other tables

```
public function retailersinfo(){

  return $this->hasOne('App\Retailers','id','refid');
}
```

we need to add `type condition (where condition =1)`.

Comment: condition? is not mentioned anywhere in your post or is just generic or?

Comment: @mrhn i have to do like return $this->hasone('App\Retailers','id','refid')->where('type',1);

Comment: and type is based on the current models column and which one?

Comment: @mrhn it is current models column

Comment: Guess you should have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations. I think you have perfect use case for it